# Homebrew formula: use dependency from a custom tap

Tags: macos, homebrew

Say I have an app which I'd like to distribute via a custom Homebrew tap so that any potential user of the app could install it via

```
brew tap <github_account>/<appname>
brew install <appname>
```

My app has a dependency on some thirdparty library. It is not present in the official Homebrew repository, but it is present in *another* custom Homebrew tap. So while I could just include the library in my own tap and have it a dependency for my app in the formula, it feels the right thing to do to reuse the library's packaging from the existing tap.

So my question is: is it possible to specify a dependency from a custom tap within the Homebrew formula?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can.

For example, assume you want to install a formula `baz` in Github repo `foo/homebrew-bar` as dependency, write like this.

```
depend_on "foo/bar/baz"
```

(FYI `foo` is Github user name, `homebrew-bar` is a Github repo by `foo`)

This will tap `foo/homebrew-bar` automatically, install `baz`.

Even if the dependency formula is not on Github, you can specify full URL for the formula.
(Though I haven't examined fully)

```
depends_on "http://www.somewhere.com/some_formula.rb"
```